# smbclient sees file but cant find it

Tags: windows, ubuntu, smbclient

I have been using smbclient to grab files from a windows file system to an ubuntu based computer. It was working up until a few weeks ago. From ubuntu I do:
`smbclient -A ./credentialsFile //IP/path/to/folder -c`
at that point I am in the directory. I then do
`mask ""` and
`mget file.txt`
it responds with
`get file file.txt?` 
I type y
it then states
`failed to open \IP\path\to\folder\file.txt NT_STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND`

I can manually use get to grab individual files. If I try to follow the same procedure to just grab the directory (`mget folder` (after `recurse ON`), it doesnt error, but also doesnt download any files.

this is the overall command that used to work:
`smbclient -A ~/.credentials //IP/path/to/ -c 'mask ""; recurse ON; prompt OFF; mget folder;'` . Now it doesnt error but it also does nothing.

How can it know what file I am talking about yet be unable to find it?

Comment: if I instead do `smbclient -A ~/.credentials //IP/path/to/ -c 'mask ""; recurse ON; prompt OFF; cd folder; mget *;' ` it goes through each and every file in that folder telling me that it could not find that file.

Comment: Have you tried `smbget` ? See [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/562702/copy-file-from-windows-to-linux).  I myself would probably `mount` the share, `rsync`, `umount` the share.. but that is just me.

Comment: smbget worked! thanks

Comment: Totally! :)  Glad to help.  I am going to mark this as a duplicate and let the people with magic powers clean it up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [copy file from windows to Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/562702/copy-file-from-windows-to-linux)